# Skip two or more than two iterations in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to skip 2 iterations using continue in for loop. But continue skip only single iteration. Could anyone let me know how to skip two or more iterations?

```
numbers = [
951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544,
615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 237, 865, 575, 219, 390
]
for number in numbers:
if number == 237:
    continue
print(number)
```

I want to skip number 360, 263 and 980 too.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Do you want to skip more iterations after a specific element is found or want to skip multiple elements? Your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use iterator function `iter(numbers)` and function `next()`. They are all built-in.

```
numbers_to_skip = [237, 360, 263, 980] 
numbers_iter = iter(numbers)
for number in numbers_iter:
    if number in numbers_to_skip:
        next(numbers_iter)
        continue
    print(number)
```

Comment: Hi, How to skip number 360, 263 and 980 too?

Comment: @Karen edited my ans. If you have more numbers to skip, just add them to the list

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip n numbers after the match, you could use a counter. For example, if you want to skip any 69 and the two following number (total 3) you could do:

```
to_skip = 0
for number in numbers:
    if number == 69:
        to_skip = 3
    if to_skip > 0:
        to_skip -= 1
            continue
        print(number)
```

Here any 69 in the list will reset the counter which may be or not what you want...

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny: Oops... Thanks for your comment. I had stupidly mixed spaces and tabs...

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```py
iter_to_skip = [LIST OF NUMBERS TO SKIP ITERATION]
numbers = [
951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544,
615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390
]
for number in numbers:
  if number in iter_to_skip:
    continue
  print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicit create an iterator of the list. But you have to be careful not to throw an StopIteration exception if there are no items left in the iterator to skip.

An example with simpler items to follow the iteration

```
numbers = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
]
iternums = iter(numbers)
skip = 4
for number in iternums:
  if number == 2:
    try: 
      [next(iternums) for _ in range(skip-1)]     # skip next iterations
    except StopIteration:
      break
    continue
  print(number)
```

Out:

```
1   # 2 and three following skipped
6
7
8
9
10
```